# Can I go back to the previous Ubuntu version after installing 11.04 alpha2?

Tags: networking, 11.04

After installing 11.04 alpha2, I cannot access the internet.

I use wireless LAN. In the *network connection* dialog, it seems to work well, but I cannot access any webpages from my webbrowser even if I use direct ip address (so it is not a DNS problem).

I cannot download a newer version from update-manager. That doesn't work either.

Can I roll back the update? I'm so frustrated and regretful.

Comment: Please see: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate

Comment: Might sneak in under can I rollback the update.  Probably not.  As to the networking stuff not working, I would lean towards a driver issue as natty networkmanager et al works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Windows Ubuntu doesn't create system restore points to 'rollback' to.

You would have to reinstall 10.10 from scratch but you can back up your data in your /home directory and start over.

Natty is only an Alpha release and not recommended for a production install - you'd be better off to install it onto a USB stick and run a live version to test and report bugs.

Comment: Thank you. I just reinstalled 10.10. I'm not gonna taste alpha version again! T.T

Comment: I recommend you install to usb as detailed on Jono Bacon's blog http://www.jonobacon.org/2010/11/30/testing-natty-and-unity-safely-with-a-usb-stick/